# Why does line 34 return: TypeError: 'int' does not support indexing

Tags: python, list, turtle-graphics

I can't execute this code because of a TypeError in the next line

t.goto(a[y])
(I'm a starter btw so please elaborate as much as possible)

```
    a = [(285.316954889, 92.7050983125),(242.705098312,176.335575688),(176.335575688, 242.705098312),(92.7050983125,285.316954889),(0.0, 300.0),(-92.7050983125, 285.316954889),(-176.335575688, 242.705098312),(-242.705098312, 176.335575688),(-285.316954889, 92.7050983125),(-300.0, 0.0),(-285.316954889,-92.7050983125),(-242.705098312, -176.335575688),(-176.335575688,-242.705098312),(-92.7050983125, -285.316954889),(0.0, -300.0),(92.7050983125, -285.316954889),(176.335575688, -242.705098312),(242.705098312, -176.335575688),(285.316954889, -92.7050983125),(300.0, 0.0)]

    y = 0

    for x in a:
     for b in range(20):
       t.goto(a[y])
       y = y + 1
```

Comment: Can you post the complete script? Also, could you please explain what would be the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

This error is because you have 2 definitions for `a`.

```
a = [(285.316954889, 92.7050983125),(242.705098312,176.335575688),(176.335575688, 242.705098312),(92.7050983125,285.316954889),(0.0, 300.0),(-92.7050983125, 285.316954889),(-176.335575688, 242.705098312),(-242.705098312, 176.335575688),(-285.316954889, 92.7050983125),(-300.0, 0.0),(-285.316954889,-92.7050983125),(-242.705098312, -176.335575688),(-176.335575688,-242.705098312),(-92.7050983125, -285.316954889),(0.0, -300.0),(92.7050983125, -285.316954889),(176.335575688, -242.705098312),(242.705098312, -176.335575688),(285.316954889, -92.7050983125),(300.0, 0.0)]

y = 0

for x in a:
 for a in range(20): <----- a is an integer
   t.goto(a[y])
   t.goto(0,0)
   y = y + 1
```

`a` starts as a list, but in the second for loop, becomes an integer. The line `t.goto(a[y])` is attempting to access the integer `a` variable. To fix this, simply rename the second `a` as follows:

```
a = [(285.316954889, 92.7050983125),(242.705098312,176.335575688),(176.335575688, 242.705098312),(92.7050983125,285.316954889),(0.0, 300.0),(-92.7050983125, 285.316954889),(-176.335575688, 242.705098312),(-242.705098312, 176.335575688),(-285.316954889, 92.7050983125),(-300.0, 0.0),(-285.316954889,-92.7050983125),(-242.705098312, -176.335575688),(-176.335575688,-242.705098312),(-92.7050983125, -285.316954889),(0.0, -300.0),(92.7050983125, -285.316954889),(176.335575688, -242.705098312),(242.705098312, -176.335575688),(285.316954889, -92.7050983125),(300.0, 0.0)]

y = 0

for x in a:
 for b in range(20): <---- note the use of b
   t.goto(a[y])
   t.goto(0,0)
   y = y + 1
```

Comment: "does not work" is not helpful.  Tell us what is actually happening.

Comment: I'm assuming the second for loop has a purpose, but the code you gave does not reflect this. It looks like a drawing type problem where it goes to each point, and then back to `(0,0)`. The second loop just causes this to repeat 20 times before moving to the next point.

Answer (score 0):

> but it still does not work

Avoid the messy indexing and simply loop over the content of your array:

```
import turtle as t

a = [(285.316954889, 92.7050983125), (242.705098312, 176.335575688),
     (176.335575688, 242.705098312), (92.7050983125, 285.316954889), (0.0, 300.0),
     (-92.7050983125, 285.316954889), (-176.335575688, 242.705098312),
     (-242.705098312, 176.335575688), (-285.316954889, 92.7050983125), (-300.0, 0.0),
     (-285.316954889, -92.7050983125), (-242.705098312, -176.335575688),
     (-176.335575688, -242.705098312), (-92.7050983125, -285.316954889), (0.0, -300.0),
     (92.7050983125, -285.316954889), (176.335575688, -242.705098312),
     (242.705098312, -176.335575688), (285.316954889, -92.7050983125), (300.0, 0.0)
]

t.penup()

for position in a:
    t.setheading(t.towards(position))
    t.goto(position)
    t.pendown()

t.exitonclick()
```